# Perché i Fucilieri di Marina si chiamano Marò?

Tags: history, abbreviations

I fucilieri della [Brigata Marina San Marco](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brigata_marina_%22San_Marco%22) della Marina Militare si chiamano *Marò*. Perché? È un sinonimo di *marinai*? Qual è la storia di questa parola? La parola non mi suona toscana.

---

<sub>[Perché la Brigata Marina San Marco ha adottato il leone alato di Venezia?](https://history.stackexchange.com/q/72126/17887)</sub>

Comment: https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/maro_res-b00b0b9e-0024-11de-9d89-0016357eee51

Comment: Grazie. Quello sarebbe una buona risposta

Comment: @DaG If you don't want to post an answer, can I post one based on your link?

Comment: Of course, but I'm not sure there is material enough for an answer. For instance, I'm curious too about why there is this unusual ending in -ò rather than, say, *“mari” or something.

Comment: @DaG The -ò ending is much of the motivation for this question, indeed

Comment: About the ending in -ò, see https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/1%C2%BA_Reggimento_%22San_Marco%22, which says "marò» (from the bureaucratic abbreviation «mar.o»,  for«marinaio»)'. Therefore, it is natural to pronounce this abbreviation with *ò*, because there is the full stop, a pause, before -o.

Comment: Tra l'altro, perché pensi che la parola dovrebbe essere toscana? Il nome del battaglione San Marco viene da Venezia, anche se, come leggo nella voce di Wikipedia, i marinai venivano un po' da tutta Italia, in primis ovviamente da città di mare.

Comment: Secondo il [*Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](https://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI09/00000834.jpg), l'etimologia è incerta, ma alcuni lo fanno derivare dal greco μωρός, che significa sciocco, semplice.

Comment: A me sembra molto strano che venga da  μωρός, perché la pronuncia è moròs, con la *o*, poi non capisco il nesso tra il battaglione San Marco e l'esser sciocchi, quello dovrebbe essere un corpo scelto. Poi che c'entra la marina militare italiana con il greco antico? Però se lo dice una ragione ci sarà, ma non la capisco.

Comment: @BakerStreet Quando ho scritto parola toscana, intendevo parola italiana. Presumo che l'italiano sia la lingua ufficiale della Marina Militare Italiana.

Comment: Anche a me suona strano l'etimo dal greco antico, ma se il GDLI scrive qualcosa (anche se con la cauta premessa “alcuni lo fanno derivare da”) ci sarà un motivo: probabilmente qualche articolo di ricerca in cui viene sostenuta questa tesi, e che sarebbe utile rintracciare.

Comment: Infatti, sarebbe interessante capire i motivi. Anche perché nella vulgata popolare italiana non sono certo i marinai ad avere la fama di lenti, sciocchi, anzi, più che altro inaffidabili: promesse da marinaio, marinaio, una donna in ogni porto. Che gente di mare sia considerata lenta e stupida è strano.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si trova qualche informazione nel libro [*Ricerche linguistiche balcanico-danubiane* di Giovan Battista Pellegrini (La Fenice Edizioni, 1992)](https://dokumen.pub/qdownload/ricerche-linguistiche-balcanico-danubiane-9788886171007-8886171005.html). In una discussione sull'etimologia di *mòro*, si menziona anche *marò* come una voce derivata dal veneziano usata nella marina adriatica per i marinai «di fatica» il cui origine potrebbe collegarsi al greco:

> Conviene riportare innanzi tutto il lemma del Boerio (fin dalla
> prima edizione del 1829 p. 361): «*morè* m. T. Mar. ragazzo di scopa.
> Chiamasi il servo o il garzone che in una barca s'impegna in qualsivoglia fatica e particolarmente nel nettare il bastimento e nel servir l'equipaggio. *Morè* in greco moderno è il vocativo di *morós* che vuol
> dire «nero», ma oltre che in questi sensi usasi come appellativo
> familiare equivalente ad «Ehi tu!» o simile. Anche noi diciamo *vien
> qua moro*; *sta quieto moro mio* e simili. Queste osservazioni fanno
> presumere che la voce *morè* venga da *more* greco, per la ragione forse
> che quei ragazzi sono chiamati dall'equipaggio con quelle voci confidenziali».
> La spiegazione della voce nella nostra nota è in buona parte
> contenuta in questo lemma, assai puntuale, del Boerio; ma questi
> rivela subito una scarsa conoscenza del greco, e d'altro canto coloro
> che si sono poi occupati di *morè* non hanno saputo presentare un
> quadro completo del problemino di cui stiamo discutendo. 
>       Merita riportare anche un lemma parallelo del DEI,
> sempre attento ai regionalismi; nel vol. IV pp. 2507-8 leggiamo infatti: *morè* m.
> (XIX sec. Boerio) «marò»; v. venez. cfr. l'abr. *murè* marinaretto che
> nelle barche da pesca sale sull'antenna per legare la vela; gr. mod.
> *mōré*, *mōré’* ohé! ohi tu! caro (mio); dal vocat. di *môron*, *mōró(n)*
> bambino, da *môros* matto, semplice, sciocco, fatuo, stravagante, cfr.
> gr. m. *morudóki* bambino. Passato al serbo-croato *mòre* come interiezione».
> Sempre il DEI III, 2371 riporta *marò* m. XIX s. mar. ragazzo
> di fatica nei bastimenti, v. usata nella marina adriatica (ven. *morè*)
> dal. gr. *mōrós* bambino (da pazzo, stolto)». Ma una trattazione assai
> ampia e precisa della voce veneziana riportata dal Boerio si trova in
> M. Cortelazzo, *L'influsso linguistico greco a Venezia*, Bologna (Pàtron) 1970, p. 148
> s.v. *morè*. Essa mi esenta da ripetere una lunga
> sequela di citazioni, specie marinaresche, tra le quali soprattutto
> quelle del *Diz. di Marina* (con lemma redatto da A. Prati). Il greco
> μωρέ «usato scherzosamente fin dal II sec. d.C. (Sophocles II, 776)
> vocat. di μωρός «stolto, sciocco», Liddell Scott 1158, è espressione citata
> anche da Matteo 7.26, di vario e frequente uso e tuttora
> vivacissima in Grecia ed in tutta la penisola balcanica, ove ha avuto
> una straordinaria fortuna...». [...]
>
>       Per collegare la voce veneta (ed in particolare veneziana)
> con espressioni balcaniche mi ha offerto l’occasione [...].

In effetti, sulla pagina 101 dell'Ottocententesco [*Vocabolario portabile del dialetto veneziano*](https://archive.org/details/ContariniVocabolarioVeneziano/mode/1up) si trova la voce che segue:

> **Morè**. (term. marin.) Garzone di barca.

Quindi, secondo il *Dizionario etimologico italiano* (DEI), il termine *marò* si sarebbe cominciato a usare nella marina adriatica nel XIX secolo e avrebbe origine nel veneziano *morè*. S
Il [*Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](https://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI09/00000834.jpg) riporta  che l'etimologia del termine rimane incerta, cioè, non è tanto chiara la derivazione dal greco (su questa fonte si può leggere la cauta dichiarazione "alcuni lo fanno derivare dal greco").